# Passing and assign data to state using Composition API in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I new in web programming and I try to make simple dynamic web using Vue.
I have a little problem with passing and assign data to state using composition API. Here the snippet code :

Main.vue :

```
export default defineComponent({
    setup(_, { root: { $api } }) {

    const state = reactive({
      isFetching: true,
      build: [],
      data:{},
      searches: {
         name: [],
         age: []
      },
    });

onMounted(async () => {
  // get data from API
  state.data = dataFromAPI;   
});

const onSearch = (state2) => {
    ....
};

return {
  ...toRefs(state),
  tableHeaders,
  onSearch,
  pagination: {
    rowsPerPage: 10,
  },
};
```

Child.vue :

```
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        searches: { type: Object, required: true },
    },
    setup(_, { emit }) {
        const state = reactive({
           name: ref(null), // I need assign this with value that I get from API in Main.vue
           age: ref(null),
        });

   const onSearch = () => {
       emit('onSearch', { ...state });
   };

   return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      onSearch,
   };
});
```

I need to passing data and assign that data which I get from API in Main.vue to state in Child.vue. Few days ago I didn't try with composition API and I success pass the data between parent to child or child to parent but I got confused with composition API. I read the composition API documentation but not find any answer.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: So I get -1 because 'Thanks In Advance' word?? Honestly I'm bad in english so I try to as politely as possible when asking help. But I will note that never say thanks in Stack Overflow

Comment: Don't worry excessively about downvotes - they are just messages, and should not be taken personally. The downvote is meant to be a helpful indicator - in this case it means that I've made 15 technical writing edits on your material, and still the questions are being written as if Stack Overflow is a chatroom.

Comment: So, no, the downvote is not for a single chatty question, it's for persisting with chatty questions when you know that is not the preferred format. Please try to refrain from conversational material if you can - the ideal format is that questions read like documentation. No fluff, just information. I have withdrawn the downvote for now in the hope you can change course.